# Scooter stalling when idle and warm

Tags: stall, carburetor, scooter, moped

I have a 50cc scooter gy6 and it dies when stopping at traffic lights or when idle in general.

it has a brand new carburator.

Things I have noticed: 
When it is cold it does not do it that often but when it warms up it does it quite a lot more.

When I try to start it back up, it does not start unless I use the throttle.

for similar cases online I have read that it might be caused because I am running reach. So I have to turn the screw mixture in the carburateur in.

How can I know what I have to do? I read that I can tell by looking at the spark plug but not sure what to look for.

Any hints?

Comment: If it has a carburetor it may be dirty or need adjusting.

Comment: @Moab it has a new carb (updated the original question with this addition)

Comment: Is it adjustable for idle mixture?

Comment: @Moab yes I have found the screw for adjusting the mixture. I don't know if I should make it richer or leaner

Comment: make it richer, 1/4 turn at a time while hot until the hot idle is good.